# How to share a property amongst several C# classes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have several classes which inherit from different classes.
All those classes have a session property (which they define or inherit).

I'd like to add a property to all those classes :

```
public SessionObject SessionObject
{
    get
    {
        return Session["SessionObject"] as SessionObject;
    }
    set
    {
        Session["SessionObject"] = value;
    }
}
```

But I don't see how.

I think in C++ I could just use a template, but I don't see Generics doing that.

How can it be done?

Comment: Do they all implement a similar interface? Where does `Session` come from?

Comment: use interfaces, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b.aspx

Comment: @dotctor interface cannot implement setter of property

Comment: If they can't share a base class, you could use an interface to declare `Session` and write extension methods instead of using a property.

Comment: Or you could add an extra layer of abstraction between these classes and `Session`, e.g. a `SessionContainer` class that has your `SessionObject` property on it.

Comment: @AntP aren't extension method last resort solutions?

Comment: @SergeProfafilecebook Not necessarily. It depends on the context, which we don't have.

Comment: Classes might do an intensive use of the SessionObject property

Comment: @SergeProfafilecebook You're not using LINQ then? Or any IoC container? Those use extension methods quite extensively...

Comment: In c# a class can only inherit from one class. Multiple inheritance is not supported.

Comment: ...or you can use something like this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/386911/Csharp-Easy-Extension-Properties

Comment: You don't need multiple inheritance - you should be able to accomplish the same thing with composition. The OP just needs help to think more along those lines rather than C++ way of doing things.

Comment: @code4life yes, the OP need to implement an interface.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a finite number of options for sharing the *implementation* across multiple types

1. If all your objects share a common base class already, add it there. If they do not use inheritance at all, you could define a base class - however C# allows only one implemenation inheritance
2. Use composition, this involves writing a class with just your property and having that property on all classes (see example 1)
3. Use extension methods - you could do this on a "marker" interface (with no actual methods) or on the objects themselves (see example 2)

---

Example 1

```
public class SessionContainer
{

    public SessionObject SessionObject
    {
        get
        {
            return Session["SessionObject"] as SessionObject;
        }
        set
        {
            Session["SessionObject"] = value;
        }
    }
}

public class YourClass1
{
    public SessionContainer Session { get; private set; }

    public YourClass1
    {
        this.Session = new SessionContainer();
    }
}

public class YourClass2
{
    public SessionContainer Session { get; private set; }

    public YourClass2
    {
        this.Session = new SessionContainer();
    }
}
```

---

Example 2 (using a marker interface which is empty)

```
public interface ISessionContainer{}

public static class SessionExtensions
{
    public static SessionObject GetSessionObject(this ISessionContainer session)
    {
        return session["SessionObject"] as SessionObject;
    }

    public static void SetSessionObject(this ISessionContainer session, 
                                                SessionObject obj)
    {
        session["SessionObject"] = obj;
    }

}

public class YourClass1 : ISessionContainer{}
public class YourClass2 : ISessionContainer{}
```

Answer (score 3):

A couple of options (assuming you can't just make an abstract class and use it as a base class for everything).

Use an interface and a pair of extension methods:

```
public interface IHasSession
{
    public Session Session { get; set; }
}

public static class HasSessionExtensions
{
    public static void SetSessionObject(this IHasSession subject, SessionObject value)
    {
        subject.Session["SessionObject"] = value;
    }

    public static SessionObject GetSessionObject(this IHasSession subject)
    {
        return subject.Session["SessionObject"] as SessionObject;
    }
}
```

Or use a wrapper class for your session:

```
public class SessionWrapper
{
    public Session Session { get; set; }

    public SessionObject SessionObject
    {
        get
        {
            return Session["SessionObject"] as SessionObject;
        }
        set
        {
            Session["SessionObject"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And put that on your other classes instead:

```
public SessionWrapper SessionWrapper { get; set; }
```

Then you only need to implement it once and can access it via:

```
var obj = myThing.SessionWrapper.SessionObject;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a property, you can make 2 extension methods on the object type:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static void SetSessionObject(this object o, SessionObject value) 
    {
        Session["SessionObject"] = value;
    }

    public static SessionObject GetSessionObject(this object o)
    {
        return Session["SessionObject"] as SessionObject;
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
youClassInstance.GetSessionObject();
```

Comment: extending `object` seems blunt

Comment: You don't have to extend it, `object` is just the base class of every class.

Comment: This wont compile. `this object` is missing the parameter name - should be `this object obj` or similar. Also `value` in the setter does not have a coresponding parameter

Comment: `o` is also unused in the extension methods! And there is no `value` parameter!

Comment: Extension method on `object` for this is akin to banging a pin-nail with a sledgehammer.

Comment: Additionaly, there will many types that inherit from `object` where `Session` will by meaningless.

Comment: Sure, but I guess that he can't let all his classes inherit from another user-defined base class. So, it seems the only choice to me.

Comment: @king.code - see the other answers, you can define an extension method on something a bit more specific than `object`

Answer (score -1):

Create one base class with this property and make it root class for all your classes. Create Pyramid :-)

Comment: He wrote that his classes already inherit from other different classes. C# allows only one implementation inheritance.